# PoweShellにてPowerPointのファイルをPDFにエクスポートしたい。

Tags: windows, powershell, powerpoint

PowerShellにてPowerPointのファイルをPDFにエクスポートしたいです。
下記のように書いてみましたが、PowerPoint.Application.PpFixedFormatType:TypeNameが上手く認識してくれません。

```
$Path = ".\testpdf.pdf"
$mtrue = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
$mfalse = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
$ppt = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
$pre = $ppt.Presentations.Open($Path,$mfalse,$mtrue, $mtrue)

$FixedFormatType = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatType]::ppFixedFormatTypePDF
$pre.ExportAsFixedFormat($Path,$FixedFormatType)
```

エラーとして下記のように表示されてしまいます。

```
"ExportAsFixedFormat" の設定中に例外が発生しました: 型 "PpFixedFormatType" の "ppFixedFormatTypePDF" 値を型 "Object" に
変換できません。
発生場所 行:1 文字:1
+ $pre.ExportAsFixedFormat($Path , $FixedFormatType)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

`SaveAs`メソッドを使って、PDFにエクスポートできることは確認したのですが、`ExportAsFixedFormat`で失敗することが気になって仕方がないです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: この記事あたりが参考になるかもしれません。[PowerPoint 2007 SP2, ExportAsFixedFormat in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/893675/9014308), [Exporting PPT presentation to PDF from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63817805/9014308), [PowerPoint ExportAsFixedFormat in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4086541/9014308)

Comment: PowerPoint 2007 SP2, ExportAsFixedFormat in PowerShell?の回答の一番最後が参考になりました。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1):

コメントで頂いたリンクを参照してみて実験し、下記コードで出力成功しました。

MSのサイトでは省略可能ですが、必須になってそうな感じでしょうか？
[MSのサイト](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.exportasfixedformat)

```
$ppt = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
    $mtrue = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
    $mfalse = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse
    $pre = $ppt.Presentations.Open($Sfile,$mfalse,$mtrue, $mtrue)

    $FixedFormatType = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatType]::ppFixedFormatTypePDF
    $Intent = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatIntent]::ppFixedFormatIntentScreen
    $FrameSlides = $mfalse
    $HandoutOrder = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintHandoutOrder]::ppPrintHandoutVerticalFirst
    $OutputType = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintOutputType]::ppPrintOutputSlides
    $PrintHiddenSlides = $mfalse

    $sNUM = $pre.Slides.count
    $pre.PrintOptions.Ranges.Add(1,$sNUM)
    $PrintRange=$pre.PrintOptions.Ranges.Item(1)

    $pre.ExportAsFixedFormat($Path,$FixedFormatType,$Intent,$FrameSlides,$HandoutOrder,$OutputType,$PrintHiddenSlides,$PrintRange)
```